# getaddrinfo() returns only ipv6 when using AF_UNSPEC

Tags: c, networking, ipv6, ipv4, getaddrinfo

When i want to connect to a server (running locally) and don't know if the application uses ipv4, ipv6 or both, should I call `getaddrinfo()` twice, once with `AF_INET` and once with `AF_INET6`, and try all returned addresses?

Some context:
`getaddrinfo()` provides a way for ipv4/ipv6-agnostic hostname resolution. Online i found guidelines stating a common algorithm to connect to a server is to use `getaddrinfo()` with an AF_UNSPEC hint, and try addresses returned in the list.

However, in my setup, `getaddrinfo()` **only** returns an ipv6 entry when I use `AF_UNSPEC`, the host being `"localhost"`.
On the other hand, if I ask for IPv4 explicitly, `getaddrinfo()` does return an IPv4 address.

This example calls `getaddrinfo()` once with `AF_UNSPEC` and once with `AF_INET`, and iterates over the returned list and prints the address families of the entries:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <string.h>

const char* family_to_string(int family) {
    switch (family) {
        case AF_INET:
            return "AF_INET";
        case AF_INET6:
            return "AF_INET6";
        case AF_UNSPEC:
            return "AF_UNSPEC";
        default:
            return "UNKNOWN";
    }
}

int main(void) {
    struct addrinfo hints;
    struct addrinfo *res, *it;
    static const char* host = "localhost";
    static const char* port = "42420";

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = 0;
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    printf("getaddrinfo(.. %s ..):\n", family_to_string(hints.ai_family));
    int ret = getaddrinfo(host, port, &hints, &res);
    if (ret != 0) {
        return 1;
    }

    for (it = res; it != NULL; it = it->ai_next) {
        printf("entry for %s\n", family_to_string(it->ai_family));
    }
    printf("\n");
    freeaddrinfo(res);

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = 0;
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    printf("getaddrinfo(.. %s ..):\n", family_to_string(hints.ai_family));
    ret = getaddrinfo(host, port, &hints, &res);
    if (ret != 0) {
        return 1;
    }

    for (it = res; it != NULL; it = it->ai_next) {
        printf("entry for %s\n", family_to_string(it->ai_family));
    }
    printf("\n");
    freeaddrinfo(res);

    return 0;
}
```

It surprised me quite a bit when I received this output:

```
getaddrinfo(.. AF_UNSPEC ..):
entry for AF_INET6

getaddrinfo(.. AF_INET ..):
entry for AF_INET
```

After digging a little into the behavior of `getaddrinfo()`, it appears that it first checks for entries in `/etc/hosts`, and if it finds matching entries, it only returns those, and does not try to resolve the hostname differently.

Since my `/etc/hosts` file only contains an ipv6 entry for `localhost`, only that is returned for `AF_UNSPEC`. For `AF_INET`, the entry is not considered eligible and `localhost` is correctly resolved to `127.0.0.1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is indeed an interesting question:

This is a case, which is specially handled by the `nss-files` module of glibc; if a request for localhost with address family `AF_INET` is made and the v6 localhost entry of the /etc/hosts is parsed, it is implicitly converted to the v4 localhost entry with address `127.0.0.1`.

See `nss/nss_files/files-hosts.c` (around line 70), where this conversion is performed:

```
else if (IN6_IS_ADDR_LOOPBACK (entdata->host_addr))
  {
    in_addr_t localhost = htonl (INADDR_LOOPBACK);
    memcpy (entdata->host_addr, &localhost, sizeof (localhost));
  }
```

This branch is not taken, when asking for `AF_UNSPEC`, so you will only resolv a v4 localhost address when having an explicit entry in `/etc/hosts` for it.

Comment: Which leads me to the next question: Is the glibc behavior conformant to the POSIX standard?
On p. 888 of the standard, it says:
"If a specific family is not given and the name could be interpreted as valid within multiple supported families, the implementation shall attempt to resolve the name in all supported families and, in absence of errors, one or more results shall be returned."

Comment: @madmax1 I do not believe that this issue is specified in detail by posix. It probably was a pragmatical fix for some common problem, looks indeed a bit ugly.

Comment: Reading the standard, it sounds like it should try to resolve the hostname using **all** protocols. (see comment above)

Comment: @madmax1 In my eyes, the funny thing is _not_ that a request for `AF_UNSPEC` does not yield a v4 localhost address, but that a request for `AF_INET` _does_.

Comment: So do you think i should anticipate a setup in which i cannot reach `"localhost"` via IPv4?

Comment: @madmax1 Sorry, I do not understand what you mean. _Usually_ there is an entry for localhost ipv4 _and_ localhost ipv6 in /etc/hosts, so there shouldn't be an issue at all on a sane system

Comment: @madmax1 IPv6 is the default protocol, and IPv4 is deprecated, so yes, eventually you will find that `localhost` does not work on IPv4. Some OSes (like Windows) explicitly support removing IPv4 entirely, so localhost would _only_ work on IPv6 today. There are already such machines in production.